# Proving the equality $\int |f|^p = \int_0^\infty pt^{p-1} \mu(\{x: |f(x)|\geq t\})) dt$ for $\sigma$-finite measure

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, normed-spaces

For some $\sigma$-finite measure space $(X,\mathcal{A},\mu)$ and a measurable function $f: X \to \mathbb{C}$, it is true that:

$$\int |f|^p = \int_0^\infty pt^{p-1} \mu(\{x: |f(x)|\geq t\})) dt$$

for positive, finite $p$.

I am pretty lost with this problem, and have several questions.

We can use the definition of the measure in terms of an integral to get

$$\int_0^\infty p t^{p-1} \mu(\{x:|f(x) \geq t\}) dt = \int_0^\infty pt^{p-1} \left[\int_X \chi_{\{x:|f(x) \geq t\}} 
(x) d\mu \right] dt$$

I assume the integral on the right-hand side is a Riemann integral, but can I justify doing the change of variables $u = t^{p-1}$ to obtain the following integral?

$$\int_0^\infty \mu(\{x:|f(x)|^p\geq u\}) du$$

My problem is that I have a Lebesgue integral as the integrand of (what I assume to be) the Riemann integral.

Then, how is this last integral in terms of $du$ equal to the $L_p$ norm?

Also, is it better to prove this for $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ and then extend it to $\mathbb{C}$?

It is not assumed that$\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure (at least there's no reference to that in the question).

Comment: First of all the result is only about $|f|$ so it makes no differenece whether $f$ is real valued or complex valued. Secondly when you are specifically asked to prove something about Lebesgue integrals it makes no sense to bring in Riemann integrals.

Comment: I assumed it was a Riemann integral by the convention in Bass, that $\int_{[a,b]}$ refers to a Lebesgue integral while $\int_a^b$ refers to a Riemann integral. Since this invalidates the substitution of variables used in Riemann integration, this leaves me with even less of an idea of what to do. Do you have any hints?

Comment: using an increasing sequence of simple functions that converge to $|f|$ the solution is straightforward. That is: prove the statement for a simple function and after apply the monotone convergence theorem

Comment: you can show that the function defined by $\lambda (t):=\mu(\{x\in X:|f(x)|>t\})$ is decreasing and right-continuous, an so it is Riemann integrable (because it have just a countable set of jump discontinuities), so you can use the change on variable formula as you do for any Riemann integrable function