# An application of Fubini's theorem and cake layer integration.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

This problem is motivated by recent reemergence of interest in the well known identity

$$
\begin{align}
\int |f|^p\,d\mu = \int^\infty_0 p\,t^{p-1}\,\mu(|f|>t)\,dt\tag{0}\label{fubini0}
\end{align}
$$

and a the so called cake layer integration.

I am posting this as a problem because of its multiple applications in analysis, statistics and probability.

> Suppose $\nu$ is a positive Radon measure on $[0,\infty)$. Let $(X,\mathscr{F},\mu)$ be a measure space. If $f$ is a nonnegative $\mathscr{F}$-measurable function whose carrier $\{f\neq0\}$ is $\mu$ $\sigma$-finite. **Show that**
> $$
> \begin{align}
> \int_X\nu([0,f(x))\,\mu(dx) = \int^\infty_0\mu(\{f>t\})\,\nu(dt)\tag{1}\label{fubini1}
> \end{align}
> $$

In particular, if $\phi$ is absolutely continuous on any contact subintervals of $[0,\infty)$, $\phi(0)=0$ and $\nu(dt)=\phi'(t)\,dt$,

$$
\begin{align}
\int_X (\phi\circ f)\,d\mu = \int^\infty_0 \mu(\{f>t\})\,\phi'(t)\,dt\tag{3}\label{fubini2}
\end{align}
$$

---

- The most common example: $\phi(t)=t^p$ which leads to $\eqref{fubini0}$. This case has been asked many times, for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1229803/prove-int-x-fp-p-int-infty-0-tp-1-mux-fxt-dt) and more recently [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3398662/proving-the-equality-int-fp-int-0-infty-ptp-1-mu-x-fx-geq-t),
- A related question that deals with $\eqref{fubini2}$ is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/998633/how-is-fubinis-theorem-used-in-the-following-proof).

Comment: This is an year-old question, but the equality will follow (assuming the issue of $\sigma$-finiteness has been tended) directly from the Tonelli's theorem applied to $$\int_{X}\int_{0}^{\infty} \mathbf{1}_{\{f(x)>t\}} \, \nu(\mathrm{d}t)\mu(\mathrm{d}x).$$

Comment: The set $E=\{(x,t)\in X\times [0,\infty): f(x)>t\}$ is measurable in the product $\sigma$-algebra. As the carrier $\{f\neq0\}=\{f>0\}$ of $f$ is measurable and $\sigma$-finite, and $\nu$ is a Radom measure on $\mathbb{R}$, $E$ is $\sigma$-finite with respect to $\mu\otimes\nu$, that is $E$ can be covered by a countable number of integrable (with respect to $\mu\otimes\nu$) sets. The conclusion follows by Fubini-Tonelli's theorem: $\mu\otimes\nu(E)=\int_X\nu(E^t)\mu(dx)=\int_{[0,\infty)}\mu(E_x)\nu(dt)$

Comment: @SangchulLee: $\nu$, being a Radon measure on $[0,\infty)$ is certainly $\sigma$-finite. Measure $\mu$, not necessarily; however, $\{f\neq0\}$ is assumed $\sigma$-finite with respect to $\mu$.