# Prove for measures $\mu$ on $\Omega$ and $\nu$ on Borel sets, $\int_\Omega \nu[0,f(w)]\mu(dw)=\int_0^\infty \mu\{f>t\}\nu(dt)$ for any measurable $f$

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

First, I believe this question should be simple in the case where our measures are $\sigma$-finite, as there should be a direct way to rewrite these and turn it into a case of Fubini's theorem.

That is, $\nu[0,f(w))=\int_0^{f(w)} 1 d\nu$, and $\mu(x|f(x)>t)=\int_{f>t} 1 d\mu$?
Can someone help me discern how to rewrite these measures as integrals?

If what I have is correct, we then get $\int_\Omega\int_0^{f(w)}1d\nu d\mu=\int_0^{f(w)}\int_\Omega 1d\mu d\nu$ and $\int_{[0,\infty)}\mu(f>t)\nu(dt)=\int_{[0,\infty)}\int_{f>t} 1d\mu d\nu=\int_{f>t}\int_{[0,\infty)}1d\nu d\mu$, and I am a bit lost in notation to know how close this or how to proceed.

Additionally, I am unsure how to proceed in the case when we are not $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3828030/121671) and the comments.